# Ipojo Annotation - @Updated method not getting called when i update value in cfg file

Tags: java, ipojo

I have added an extra parameter in an array field of Properties file , which is not getting updated when using @updated annotation method . Please suggest the step by step procedure to use @updated ipojo annotation.

Comment: There is a probably a lot of context missing here, so the question is likely to close. What properties file are you referring to, and what does the manual say about this annotation? You've used a niche tag on its own, so you won't get many views (I've added Java, please change that to the lang you are using if that's wrong).

Comment: public void updatedConfig(Dictionary<String, String> config) { .. }

 the above method will be called whenever the configuration file (which should be in the karaf/etc folder and should be called <component_name>.cfg) is modified .   I have updated .cfg file , but @Updated method doesn't seem to be invoked .am i missing something?

Comment: ^ Please edit that information into the question, as a formatted block. I doubt that is enough information though.